# Launch yarn run script launch error whereas pure command is working (React Native Project)

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, metro-bundler

I added a script command in my package.json as following :

```
"ios": "sh config.sh && react-native run-ios"
```

This command is working fine when i do it **without** yarn.

But when i try to execute it **with** yarn (*yarn run ios* or *yarn ios*)... The command is well executed but Metro bundler is failing with this given error :

```
/Users/ano/mols/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:154
  const cmd = _commander().default.command(command.name).action(async function handleAction(...args) {
                                                                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ano/mols/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:13:11)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

Does anyone know what is going on ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably Your  NodeJS version is too old and does not support the async/await features. The syntax error is a result of the Javascript interpreter not recognizing the async token and getting confused about arguments, update your nodejs version to latest LTS.